# C++/CLI obfuscated assembly throws a MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I'm using Dotfuscator Pro 4.10 to obfuscate an application built with VS 2012. The .NET code contains managed as well as unmanaged C++/CLI code, thus compiled with /clr.

My solution contains a lot of projects. I only allow *renaming* as obfuscation. Also, as all assemblies/application are in the dotfuscator project, I don't run in library mode. Thus, all interfaces are scrambled.

When I obfuscate the assemblies everything works fine but for an assembly (let's call it *A.dll*). If I disable obfuscation for *A.dll*, the application works perfectly. If I enable obfuscation for *A.dll*, I get this:

> **Error**: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException
>
> **Message**: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "*ahe.resources*" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "*A.dll*" at compile time, or that the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

*ahe* is the scrambled name of a Window Form in *A.dll* and the exception is thrown here (from *ApplyResources()*):

```
void InitializeComponent( void )
{
    this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
    System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager( A::typeid ));

    // ...

    resources->ApplyResources( this->mpMyControl, L"mpMyControl" ); // Exception thrown here.

    // ...
}
```

The resources are correctly defined in *A.resx* (and it works before obfuscating).

Notice that this kind of code is used at many places in other assemblies and, when I disallow obfuscation for the problematic assembly *A.dll*, it works perfectly.

So, does somebody have an idea about how to solve the problem? Feel free to ask for more info/details, I don't know what could be important or not.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: None of the assemblies are signed.

Comment: Renaming obfuscations can break logic that uses reflection.  That's probably what's going on here.  Perhaps you can apply an attribute to a single class or such, to preserve its name.

Comment: Reflection... Well, I'm trying to find the reflection problem in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your root namespace is correct in .vcxproj file:

```
<RootNamespace>YourNameSpace</RootNamespace>
```

Answer (score -1):

One *Scott* has reported at
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/dotfuscator-vs-resourcemanager-ctor-t3403701.html
that this problem is addressed in the Dotfuscator's Knowledge base, which is available only to registered users of the Community edition here:
http://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator/KnowledgeBase/CommunityEdition.html .